# Laravel - Event not working - __construct() must be an instance

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to send mail to admin, when users send message to him in website. I create my events and my mailable class..

At the first, I tried without using event listener and it worked but When I tried with event listener, it didn't work..

it gives this error;

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Events\SendMessage::__construct() must be an instance of App\Contact, instance of App\Models\Contact given, called in /var/www/parti/app/Http/Controllers/ContactController.php on line 32

**Event**

```
public $mesaj;

    public function __construct(Contact $mesaj)
    {
        $this->mesaj = $mesaj;
    }
```

**Listener**

```
public function handle(SendMessage $event)
    {
        Mail::to(User::first()->email)->send(new SendMessageToAdminAsMail($event->mesaj));
    }
```

**Mail Class**

```
public $mesaj;

    public function __construct(Contact $mesaj)
    {
        $this->mesaj = $mesaj;
    }
    public function build()
    {
      return $this
         ->from($this->mesaj->email)
         ->subject($this->mesaj->name." send a message")
         ->view('backend.mail.message');
    }
```

What is my mistake ? Thank's for your help...

Comment: Seems like a namespace issue in your Event file. Show the imports at the top of the file

Comment: from which file, I need to add ?

Comment: Ops.. I found the problem.. I just move my models on models folder, I forget to change some namespaces.. thanks for your help @devk